# Get top values from a spark dataframe column in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((201601, a),
  (201602, b),
  (201603, c),
  (201604, c),
  (201607, c),
  (201604, c),
  (201608, c),
  (201609, c),
  (201605, b))).toDF("col1", "col2")
```

I want to get top 3 values of col1. Can any please let me know the better way to do this.

Spark : 1.6.2
Scala : 2.10

Comment: `df.agg(max("col1"))`  If I do this I can get the max value.

Comment: I want to know if I can retrieve top 3 values from column col1 by using spark dataframe functions. I mean without converting to date format.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like below.

```
df.select($"col1").orderBy($"col1".desc).limit(3).show()
```

You will get

```
+------+
|  col1|
+------+
|201609|
|201608|
|201607|
+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the *maxDate* firstly and then filter based on the *maxDate*:

```
val maxDate = df.agg(max("col1")).first().getAs[Int](0)
// maxDate: Int = 201609

def minusThree(date: Int): Int = {
    var Year = date/100
    var month = date%100
    if(month <= 3) { 
        Year -= 1
        month += 9
    } else { month -= 3}
    Year*100 + month
}

df.filter($"col1" > minusThree(maxDate)).show
+------+----+
|  col1|col2|
+------+----+
|201607|   c|
|201608|   c|
|201609|   c|
+------+----+
```

Comment: Good idea but if I have 201701 and if I do minus it will fail.

Comment: Hmm, correct. I missed that point. Then you probably have to convert the columns to date for convenience purpose.

Comment: I mean it will not fail but it will look for a value 201700, which will not be there

Comment: Is it possible to convert top 3 values to array. And next filter the dataframe which contains only values from array??

Comment: Like Val df1= df.where(DF(col1).Isin(array))

Comment: I updated with a little helper function to manipulate the date. I am not a fan of *OrderBy* for this type of task as it is expensive for distributed data set, even if the data is not distributed, it's an overkill to use it which extends the complexity from O(N) to O(NlogN).

Comment: Its better to convert String to Date first assign to a Variable "fromDt" and then calculate minus 3 months and assign to a another variable "toDt". And then filter the dataframe with records falling between "fromDt" and "toDt" ?

Comment: `val maxDt = df.agg(max("col1")).head().getString(0)
        val df2 = df.agg(max("col1"))
        val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM")
        val fromDt = format.parse(maxDt)`

Comment: I got the max value from the column "col1" in date format with the above approach.

Comment: Now actually I want to subtract 3 months from this maxDt variable and assign to new variable minDt. And then I want to do a df.filter($"col1" > minDt)

Comment: Psidom, I knew that you provided the helper function but I want to first convert to date format and then calculate minus 3 months and then do a filter.

Comment: Take a look at [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) and [spark date time functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), if you still have problems, plz ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get same results in one more way using top function

Example:

```
val data=sc.parallelize(Seq(("maths",52),("english",75),("science",82), ("computer",65),("maths",85))).top(2)

Results:
(science,82)
(maths,85)
```